# Alternative form of a Trigonometrics Expression

Tags: trigonometry

Express $8\sin\theta \cos\theta - 6 \sin^2 \theta$ in the form $R \sin(2\theta + \alpha) + k$

Edit: I am sorry, I thought it was a somewhat interesting question. I shall let you know of the progress I have made. I first tried to rewrite it in the form $R \sin (\theta -\alpha)$ by rewriting it as $10 (\frac{8}{10} \sin \theta \cos \theta - \frac {6}{10} \sin ^2 \theta)$. For this to have a similar form to the sine subtraction formula, I noted that therefore $\frac{6}{10}= \cot \theta$, however, I am not sure of this assertion and do not know how to proceed. I tried the standard identities already, as someone indicated below.

Comment: It is fine to ask for help if you are stuck, but you should at least tell us what you tried. Your question as stated doesn't show any effort on your part. Also, you should know that many people here find rude "questions" stated in imperative form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}8\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-6\sin^2(\theta)&=4\sin(2\theta)-3(1-\cos(2\theta))\\&=5\left(\frac{4}{5}\sin(2\theta)-\frac{3}{5}\cos(2\theta)\right)-3\end{align}$$

Notice that $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2=1$, therefore there is an angle $s=\arccos\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$ such that $\cos(s)=\frac{4}{5}$ **and** $\sin(s)=\frac{3}{5}$.

Therefore our expression can be written as

$$5\left(\sin(2\theta)\cos(s)-\cos(2\theta)\sin(s)\right)-3=5\sin(2\theta-s)-3$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $8\sin\theta\cos\theta-6\sin^2\theta=4\sin2\theta+3\cos2\theta-3$ using $2\sin^2\theta=1-\cos2\theta$. So you want
$$
R\sin(\varphi+\alpha)+k=4\sin\varphi+3\cos\varphi-3
$$
for all $\varphi$. Differentiate both sides to get
$$
R\cos(\varphi+\alpha)=4\cos\varphi-3\sin\varphi
$$
Differentiate again to get
$$
-R\sin(\varphi+\alpha)=-4\sin\varphi-3\cos\varphi
$$
Evaluate both sides of the previous identities for $\varphi=0$:
$$
\begin{cases}
R\cos\alpha=4\\
R\sin\alpha=3
\end{cases}
$$
So $R^2=16+9=25$ and $R=5$. You can choose $\alpha=\arctan(3/4)$

From the first identity with $\varphi=0$, we get
$$
R\sin\alpha+k=0
$$
so $k=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can use these helpful identities to find the answer:

$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$

$\sin^2\theta = 1-\cos^2\theta$